# What kind of load do US thermostat control signals drive?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

[This page](https://wiki.xtronics.com/index.php/Thermostat_signals_and_wiring) has some really good information on heating system wiring in America. One thing I can't tell from it though, is what exactly the 24VAC call-for-heat and call-for-cool signals drive.

Presumably they don't supply the actual power for heating or cooling (24VAC wouldn't get you far), so I guess it is some kind of control signal, but what is the load? Does it drive a relay? If so what is the coil resistance, etc.?

In other words, what exactly is in the question marks here?

[image: us thermostat wiring]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the thermostat contacts control the current to relays within the heating/cooling system. I believe the current is on the order of 100 mA.